# Change text near facebook like button

Tags: facebook-like

Is it possible to change the text near the facebook like button;

[image]

e.g. Is it possible to change the text to "Be the first of your friends to like this **item**"

The text is in a span with class connect_widget_not_connected_text, I'm trying this

```
$(".connect_widget_not_connected_text").html
```

its not working!!

Answer (score 1):

The reason this isn't work is the way how Like Button works, rendered in your page within `iframe` element which can't be accessed just like that and
is subject of cross domain policy too.

While it is possible to achieve what you want with simple CSS technique it is (probably?) violation of platform policies.

**Update:**
Take into account that wording you see depend on number of users/friends who liked specific URL and it may change, so until Facebook will provide us way to specify text that will be used (what is very unlikely to happen!) there is no reliable way to do what you want.

Comment: How would you actually change text in an iframe with CSS? (Are you thinking about _:before/:after_ and _content_-property or something?)

Comment: @CBroe, `:before`/`:after` wouldn't help much if you want to suppress last dot. I'm speaking about partially covering it with another element with greater `z-index`